# How to pass onClickEvent from NestedRecyclerView Item to the viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, clean-architecture

I have a fragment "AFragment" and a viewmodel "AViewModel" attached with the fragment. The A fragment contains a nested recyclerView. So AFragment has a recyclerview (parentRecyclerView) and the recyclerview has multiple childRecyclerView.

I used DataBinding to set the adapter of the parentRecyclerView using BindingHelper. The child recyclerview contains a list of dataClass say childModel.

The AViewModel has a liveData value, whose type of the liveData is the childModel. Whenever a childDataClass is clicked, each of them performs different operations based on some properties of the childmodel class. Whenever a childModel is clicked the onClickMethod is found in the childAdapter.

But to notify the liveData Observer, I need to post the value of the liveData of the ViewModel from the ChildAdapter.

I can have it both ways.

1. Set a callback, implement it in the fragment, and do the operations. But this can break the "clean architecture" principle, as I should not access the domain layer from the data layer.
2. Pass the viewmodel as the parameter, but i really doubt it can be a good and optimized solution.

Can someone suggest me better approach for achieving such behavior?

(Sorry but can't share the implementation here.)

Comment: There are countless tutorials out there with regards to how data is passed between the different layers in clean architecture on Android. I would argue that the answer to this is  opinion based - since you can't provide information on your implementation it's hard to give advice.